# Backup database code not working when I add a backup compression option using SMO

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, smo

Why isn't my backup database code working when I insert a compression option? The single commented line is the culprit, when I remove it the program successfully backs up. But when it isn't commented, Visual Studio has an error that says: `An unhandled exception of type System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module`.

```
Dim bk As New Backup
bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database
bk.BackupSetDescription = "Full backup of " + Main.dbname
bk.BackupSetName = Main.dbname
bk.Database = Main.dbname
//bk.CompressionOption = BackupCompressionOptions.On

Dim bdi As BackupDeviceItem
bdi = New BackupDeviceItem(backupPath + Main.dbname + ".bak", DeviceType.File)

bk.Devices.Add(bdi)
bk.Incremental = False

bk.SqlBackup(srv)

bk.Devices.Remove(bdi)
```

Comment: Are you able to post the full stack trace?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you on? Can you manually run a compressed backup by hand? What does bk.Script() return?